# How to render a FullCalendar 2.9.0 instance at full height?

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, icalendar

I want to load a remote ICS feed into [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). However, since it's not natively possible, I use [fc-remote-ical](https://github.com/cgalvarez/fc-remote-ical).

But fc-remote-ical is old and uses fullcalendar.js version 2.9.0, which does not offer an easy full-height option, like the more recent versions.

Can anybody suggest the appropriate CSS/JS I could add to [this demo](https://cgalvarez.github.io/fc-remote-ical/demo/) so that it behaves like the [full-height example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/full-height-demo) of Fullcalendar?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: The only way that remote-ical plugin interacts with fullCalendar as far as I can see is to add the data as an event source (once it's translated it). So it would be fairly easy to amend that to work with a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these CSS rules. They worked for me on your example.

- `#calendar` has a max-width of `900px`, so reset that to `100%`.
- `.fc-scroller.fc-day-grid-container` has a width set at 649px, so overwrite that.
- `.fc-day-grid.fc-unselectable` needs a set height to extend to the page
- `.fc-basic-view .fc-body .fc-row` has a few explicitly set heights. The calendar may likely always have 6 rows, so that is why I divided it by six. If there was only going to be five rows, you might need to use JS to add a class to that table that specifies the height of these.

```css
// controls width
#calendar {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

// controls height
.fc-scroller.fc-day-grid-container {
    height: 89vh!important; // tweak this value to suit your needs
    overflow: hidden; // optional
}
.fc-scroller > .fc-day-grid, .fc-scroller > .fc-time-grid {
    height: 100vh!important;
}
.fc-day-grid.fc-unselectable {
    height: 100%!important;

// controls the height of each row
.fc-basic-view .fc-body .fc-row {
    min-height: 4em;
    height: calc(100% / 6) !important;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much :)